# Can I use Sphinx automodule but drop the module name in the signature?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, qualified-name, sphinx-napoleon

I have a module `mod` with some submodule `submod` and use `.. automodule:: mod.submod` to generate documentation for it.

The signatures of the elements (functions, classes etc.) in the modules now show the qualified name, like `mod.submod.my_function(*args, **kwargs)`.

I would instead like Sphinx to just show the name of the function, i.e. the signature `my_function(*args, **kwargs)`.

Do I have any way to drop the leading module and submodules in the signature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Omitting module and package names preceding functions, methods and variables is done by setting the [`add_module_name` configuration](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-add_module_names) in your `conf.py`:

```py
add_module_names = False
```

This is not obvious because of the numerous [autodoc configurations](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#configuration) that together with the [sphinx-napoleon configurations](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#configuration) make you expect the configuration elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try this in `docs/mod/submod.rst`:

```
.. automodule:: mod.submod

    .. autofunction:: my_function
```

See example [HTML build](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html#helper-functions) and [reST source](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blame/1.10-branch/docs/api/authentication.rst#L9-L43) in Pyramid documentation.

Bonus: see the Sphinx docs for [Cross-referencing syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax):

> If you prefix the content with `~`, the link text will only be the last component of the target. For example, :py:meth:`~Queue.Queue.get` will refer to `Queue.Queue.get` but only display `get` as the link text.

Comment: Hi @Steve Piercy Thanks a lot for your reply! Unfortunately that does not seem to work for me. I've also checked out the link to the Pyramid documentation and it works there, so I am confused (but it could also be some setting in the configuration file, right?). But I didn't see something along these lines in their ``conf.py`` either...

Comment: Yes, I knew about ``~`` and I've tried if one can also apply it to this context, but unfortunately it doesn't seem so...

Comment: What do you observe? Did you do a `make clean` first? Is your code in Python packages (including `__init__.py` in the directories)? This is not a setting, but mere reST syntax for Python, and how Sphinx imports Python packages only.